# Using promise all with push array

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, promise

The code's purpose is to call to some function async given some condition was true. I've using the following code which is working as expected. Is there a way to write it better, maybe by not using the promise push array?

```
var _run = (req, res, oModule, oConfig, urlPath,action) => {

    var aPromises = [];
    //requested action to call

    for (var provider in oConfig.providers[0]) {
        if ((oConfig.providers[0][provider].val === action))
        {
            var fnName = oConfig.providers[0][provider].function;
            //Run on provided actions
            if (typeof oModule[oConfig.providers[0][provider].function] === "function") {
                try {
                    logger.info(`Function ${fnName} is called `);
                    aPromises.push(oModule[fnName](req, res));
                }
                catch (err) {
                    logger.error(`Error returned  ${err}`);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Promise.all(aPromises);
};
```

**update:**

This is the value of config object and in the code I need to call to the function according to the path I got...

```
{
  "providers": [
    {
      "run": {
        "path": "command1",
        "function": "fn1",
      },
      "save": {
        "path": "test2",
        "function": "fn2",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The loop variable `provider` isn't used, so the loop looks meaningless.

Comment: @wOxxOm - done please have a look,( i just want to make it easy to read...)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the *for* loop with *if* flow control, you could use the *arrays* functions to convert all more functional.

As your code looks broken I wrote my refactoring in the following test:

```
'use strict';

// This is just to run the test    
const request = {}
const response = {}

// This is a trivial oModule object
const M = {
    fn1: function() {
        return new Promise(() => console.log('fn1'))
    },
    fn2: function() {
        return new Promise(() => console.log('fn2'))
    }
}

// This is the oConfig object as you post in your OP
const C = {
    providers: [
    {
      "run": {
        "path": "command1",
        "function": "fn1",
      },
      "save": {
        "path": "test2",
        "function": "fn2",
      }
    }
  ]
}

// The proposed refactoring
const _run = (req, res, oModule, oConfig, urlPath, action) => {
    let aPromises = Object.keys(oConfig.providers[0])
        .filter(providerName => (providerName == action))
        .map(providerName => {
            let provider = oConfig.providers[0][providerName]
            return oModule[provider.function]
        })
        .filter(func => (typeof func === 'function'))
        .map(func => func(req, res))

    return Promise.all(aPromises)
}

// This run the test to 
_run(request, response, M, C, '', 'run')
```

I used 2 different *filter/map* run to check the 2 checks on the 2 different objects *oConfig* and *oModule*.

I tested this with nodejs v4.4.4 on windows and it works without errors.

It print out:

```
fn1
```

I removed the *var* and use *const* or *let*.

It should be the same, not sure if it is more readable.

You never use *urlPath* so you can remove from arguments.

I didn't put any *;* as they are not mandatory in javascript, but if you prefere to use feel free to put at the end of each expression.

Also, I hope that *oModule[provider.function](req, res)* returns a *Promise* or your code is blocking, but maybe is so.

Comment: Thanks I've tried it and I got error oConfig.providers[0].filter is not a function ,but this is array... not sure that I got it...

Comment: Maybe you have an object and not an array, let me update the code.

Comment: Thank you , I still got error Object.values is not a function... I update the post with the full object maybe it can help, thanks for assistance...

Comment: [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is available since Chrome 51 and Firefox 47